# c# WPF OnClickEvent on listView (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I usually doesnt come here for help, but I just doesn't seems to be able to connect my treeView to my codebehind. I created it and now I would like to be able to do things when Selected item is changed (only childs). I think this is sooo basic that I havent been able to find it here, but I might havent looked deep enough. I dont have my code library with me and I cant look up a working model about the onClick event, can you help? (for now all I want to do to show some pics if a tree item is clicked, cat pics for example)

Thanks for the help

```
  Title="TheBestCatPics from Google search first page" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TreeView x:Name="CatsOnClicks"
      SelectedItemChanged="myTreeView_SelectedItemChanged"
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PeerDetailTemplate} />
        <TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Border Width="40" Height="15"></Border>
                    <Label Content= "TheCats, Majestic...."></Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
        </TreeViewItem>
            <!-- Child Item -->

            <TreeViewItem SelectedItemChanged="OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged">
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Cica"></Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Cicus"></Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="Macska"></Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>

</Grid>
```

"CodeBehind":

```
namespace WpfApp___TreeViewWithCats
{
    class CatsOnClick
    {
        public object CatsOnClicks { get; set; }

        private void myTreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            CatsOnClick selectedItem = (CatsOnClick)CatsOnClicks.SelectedItem;
            // show cat pics
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what exactly do you need help with? it is unclear. on screenshot I see lots of compilation errors, please post *working* example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you clean up your code, it does work as you expect.

Here's a minimal working example (the code behind is the same as yours):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TheBestCatPics from Google search first page" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="299"
                  SelectedItemChanged="myTreeView_SelectedItemChanged"

                  Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="93">
            <TreeViewItem Header="1" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="2"/>
        </TreeView>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you see:

1. You should remove the closing slash here

   ```
   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PeerDetailTemplate} />
   ```
2. You should add closing quotes in your ItemTemplate

   ```
   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PeerDetailTemplate}"
   ```
3. You should remove the `SelectedItemChanged` event from your TreeViewItems

Comment: oh my god... I saw a few  missing <> etc... errors but somehow was under the impression that I have a logic syntax problem somewhere, thanks

Comment: Thank you for upvoting my answer then and don't hesitate to ask for more details in case you need them. By the way, if you think the proposed answer is the right one for your question, please consider marking it as such (of course don't mind if it's not the case). Best regards.

Comment: I will try it later, the problem is that this "project" is just a "self improving side quest" for me and dont really have time for it next to my job and every day activities. If I can make it run I will mark your anserw as correct